# Is it possible to dynamically set the recipient of MAILTO: with only HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, mailto

I am creating a form using only HTML and JavaScript where I want to be able to dynamically set the recipient of a POSTed form by altering the MAILTO: address or the CC address of the mailto: line. This will be determined by the value of a text box if at all possible. The purpose of this functionality is that the form data needs to be sent to a different manager depending on the choice they make in a drop down menu. I have seen this done in one place (http://javascript.internet.com/forms/multiple-mailer.html) but my issue is that I am populating my dropdown from a JS array which when selected populates some text fields just like (http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showpost.php?p=984036&postcount=8). So what I want to do is populate a hidden text input with my drop down and draw from that to determine who gets the email.

I should note that this is for a corporate INTRAnet site where lack of desktop email client is not an issue and where IE is the only browser usable. I do not have access to server-side tech so mailto is my only option, please refrain from wasting comments telling me how bad an idea it is, lol. Thanks!

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open the mail client with some email address:

```
location = 'mailto:' + email_address;
```

To set the `href` of an `a` element, first get it using something like `document.getElementById`, then set the `href` property:

```
document.getElementById('someLink').href = 'mailto:' + email_address;
```

`email_address` is a string containing the applicable email address -- you can replace this with an expression that gets the value of the dropdown:

```
document.getElementById('someLink').href = 'mailto:' + document.getElementById('dropdown').value;
```

Comment: I may just be really dumb but I have having some difficulty implementing this. Could anyone post an example of how this fits in with the basic form header:   <form id="infoSubmit" action="MAILTO:email@company.com?CC=otherguy@company.com&Subject=This is the email's subject" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

Comment: `document.getElementById('infoSubmit').action = 'mailto:' + email_address;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the `href` attribute to a string containing an email address using Javascript.

Comment: Could you provide an example or a link to one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I have an option box in my form similar to this:

```
<td><select name="Division" id="Division" onChange="dirChange()" tabindex="3">
<option selected>Choose One</option>
<option value="Communications">Communications</option>
<option value="Legal Services">Legal Services</option>
</select>        &nbsp;</td>
```

It refers to a javascript function:

```
function dirChange()
{
var i = document.all.Division.value;
switch (i)
{

    case "Communications":
        document.all.DeputyDirector.value = "Dave C.";
        document.all.form.action = "mailto:Dave.C@xxxxx.com?subject=Form";
        break;

    case "Legal Services":
        document.all.DeputyDirector.value = "Dixie P.";
        document.all.form.action = "mailto:Dixie.P@xxxxxx.com?subject=Form";
        break;

    default:
        document.all.DeputyDirector.value = "";
        break;

}
}
```

This javascript then helps fill in the needed information on a text box and for the form to email to the selected person.

```
<tr>
  <td class="announcementText"> <span class="style12"><span class="style16"><span class="style31">*</span></span></span>Division Deputy Dir.:  </td>
  <td><input name="DeputyDirector" type="text" id="DeputyDirector" style="background-color:#cccccc; color:black; font-weight:bold; border:0; overflow:visible" size="38"></td>

</tr>

<form onChange="dirChange()" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="form" id="form"   onSubmit="return checkform(this);">
```

The resulting html for the client, once they select a communications division is:
for the text box:

```
<input name="DeputyDirector" type="text" id="DeputyDirector" style="background-color:#cccccc; color:black; font-weight:bold; border:0; overflow:visible" size="38" value = "Dave C.">
```

and for the form:

```
<form onChange="dirChange()" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="form" id="form"   onSubmit="return checkform(this); action = "mailto:Dave.C@xxxxx.com?subject=Form">
```

or if they select legal services
for the text box:

```
<input name="DeputyDirector" type="text" id="DeputyDirector" style="background-color:#cccccc; color:black; font-weight:bold; border:0; overflow:visible" size="38" value = "Dixie P.">
```

and for the form:

```
<form onChange="dirChange()" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="form" id="form"   onSubmit="return checkform(this); action = "mailto:Dixie.P@xxxxxx.com?subject=Form">
```