# Can I dynamically set the recipient of mailto: using only HTML and JavaScript depending on URL used to access the site?

Tags: javascript, html, email, dynamic, mailto

I have 5 different websites that all use the same privacy html page but depending on which site they accessed it from I want the email to change dynamically.

For example, lets say I access the privacy page from Site A and click the privacy@example.com to send an email I want that email to be sent to privacy-siteA@example.com, if I access the same privacy page from Site B and click the same email I want it to send to privacy-siteB@example.com.

Is something like this possible with just HTML and JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to dynamically set the recipient of MAILTO: with only HTML and JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867613/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-the-recipient-of-mailto-with-only-html-and-ja)

Comment: Yea I looked at that earlier but that's grabbing from a dropdown selection which doesn't apply to what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var l=window.location+'';
l=l.replace(/http(s*):\/\/(www\.)*/,'');
l=l.split('/')[0]; //get the domain
var mailto='privacy-'+l+'@example.com';
```

Comment: This makes sense to me but what would I put in the a href=???? for this solution?

Comment: We prefer to not say "Never mind I got it" - if you can explain what you got for others, that'd be the most helpful

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on your current architecture. If you generate this privacy html page, you can add parameter to this generator.

If you have static privacy html page, you can change this email address with JS

```
document.getElementById("#your_mail_link").href="mailto:privacy-siteA@example.com";
```